# CouchDB with NodeJS authentication solution

Tags: node.js, cookies

In node.js my auth library (lockit) is not setting session after logging in successfully.  (Disclaimer: I am not condoning the use of lockit, I think it is positively terrible in every way.)

I read lockit source code and found this code:

```
    // create session and save the name and email address
    req.session.name = user.name;
    req.session.email = user.email;
```

Here is my express config:

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(cookieSession({
    secret: 'this is my super secret string'
  }));
  app.use(lockit.router);
```

After I login with a user, I send another request with the same browser and the cookie is the same that gets set from the login request...
After successful login here is the Set-Cookies I get:

```
Set-Cookie  express:sess=eyJmYWlsZWRMb2dpbkF0dGVtcHRzIjowLCJuYW1lIjoianVzdGluIiwiZW1haWwiOiJqdXN0aW5Ad2ViaW52ZXJ0ZXJzLmNvbSIsImxvZ2dlZEluIjp0cnVlfQ==; path=/; httponly

Set-Cookie  express:sess.sig=FMcv9fswWmWG6A7hpOEnEysbqd4; path=/; httponly
```

Then my request after the login contains these cookies:

```
express:sess    eyJmYWlsZWRMb2dpbkF0dGVtcHRzIjowLCJuYW1lIjoianVzdGluIiwiZW1haWwiOiJqdXN0aW5Ad2ViaW52ZXJ0ZXJzLmNvbSIsImxvZ2dlZEluIjp0cnVlfQ==

express:sess.sig    FMcv9fswWmWG6A7hpOEnEysbqd4
```

But even though the cookie is there, I'm getting:
req.session === undefined

I've never used these technologies before, so it could be something really stupid that I am doing...

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of Lockit and I'm sure we will find a solution to your problem. Did you go through all the required steps to install Lockit? Here is what I just did and it works fine.

1. Create a new Express app (Express 4.2.0 in my case).

   ```
   express
   ```
2. Install Express dependencies.

   ```
   npm install
   ```
3. Install Lockit and Sessions.

   ```
   npm install lockit cookie-session --save
   ```
4. Install CouchDB adapter.

   ```
   npm install lockit-couchdb-adapter --save
   ```
5. Create a `config.js` with the URL of your CouchDB

   ```
   // settings for local CouchDB
   exports.db = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/';
   ```
6. Initiate Lockit with your config.

   ```
   // in your header
   var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
   var Lockit = require('lockit');
   var config = require('./config.js');
   var lockit = new Lockit(config);

   // after all your other middleware
   app.use(cookieSession({
     secret: 'my super secret String'
   }));
   app.use(lockit.router);
   ```
7. Start your app.

   ```
   DEBUG=tmp ./bin/www
   ```

You can now navigate to `http://localhost:3000/signup` and create a new user. If you haven't set up any email server you have to look in your database (in my case at `http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/database.html?_users`) for your signup token. Then go to `http://localhost:3000/signup/:token` to activate your new user.

Great, you can now use your username (or email) and password to log in. To access the currently logged in user in your own routes use `req.session`.

```
// default routes from Express
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// your own custom route
app.get('/awesome', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.session.name);
  console.log(req.session.email);
  res.send('awesome');
});
```

I hope I could help you. If you've got any other problems just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:3000/signup/:token doesn't work, must be
http://localhost:3000/signup/token (without the column)